# Symfony: Add new user roles?

Tags: php, symfony, web, backend

My task is to develop an application that helps accountants and their clients communicate with each other. The website is going to have 3 types of users; an admin, an accountant and a client.

I just created my user entity with

> php bin/console make:user

but how do I add "accountant" and "client" user roles other than ROLE_USER?

Answer (score 1):

In `security.yaml` you can do this:

```
...
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ACCOUNTANT: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_CLIENT: ROLE_USER
```

So that when new users are added you can specify which flavor of `ROLE_`.